# Count until first three consecutive blank columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble mixing the counting cells with value '1' until the first three consecutive blank cells. The following image as the example:

[image]

Is it possible to do it only with Excel formulas or do I have to use other code?

Comment: It's possible with formulas, but the way I can think of doing it would not be too pretty. I'm thinking the best way might just be a macro.

Comment: Are columns AA AB and AC populated or are they guaranteed blank?

Comment: Do it @Jeeped Post your answer.

Comment: @findwindow - Didn't know you shilled for Nike. :)

Comment: Tyvm for all the help :)
@ Jeeped i will use much more columns than AC, but i just modified your formulas to higher range, TY. :)

Comment: @Jeeped lol nah, your comment above suggested you have something in mind completely unique and I always learn something from you. But now that you mentioned it, I am going to call Nike...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not so much identifying the three terminating blank cells as trailing the last three blank cells off to 2 cells then 1 cell at the end of the B:Z range. If you can extend the range to guaranteed blank cells in AA:AC then you can use an **array formula¹** to accomplish the 'three-blank-cell-match' with a progressively staggered range.

[image: locate three blank cells]

The **array formula¹** in A2 is,

```
=COUNTIF(B2:INDEX(B2:AA2, MATCH(1E+99, IF(B2:AA2="", IF(C2:AB2="", IF(D2:AC2="", 1E+99))), 0)), 1)
```

Fill down as necessary.

> counting cells with value '1' until the first three consecutive ...

The formula may be more universal if counting ones is the primary task. Simply switch the conditions to any three consecutive cells that are not **i**.

[image: stagger three non-one consecutive cells]

The **array formula¹** in A2 is,

```
=COUNTIF(B2:INDEX(B2:AA2, MATCH(1E+99, IF(B2:AA2<>1, IF(C2:AB2<>1, IF(D2:AC2<>1, 1E+99))), 0)), 1)
```

Fill down as necessary. Note that I've modified the last row to show more matches.

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula.</sub>

Comment: I realize this was not in the spec, but can you make it so that it still works if OP instead wish to count non-blank cells?

Comment: You mean *any three consecutive non-one cells*? Stop at any three cells that do not contain a **1**? The OP had originally stated*'counting cells with value '1''*. I do not know why everyone else was using [COUNT](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/COUNT-function-a59cd7fc-b623-4d93-87a4-d23bf411294c) instead of [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34).

Answer (score 2):

Enter this formula in cell A2 and then copy downward as far as needed:

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET(B2,,,,-1+FIND("111",--(B2="")&--(C2="")&--(D2="")&--(E2="")&--(F2="")&--(G2="")&--(H2="")&--(I2="")&--(J2="")&--(K2="")&--(L2="")&--(M2="")&--(N2="")&--(O2="")&--(P2="")&--(Q2="")&--(R2="")&--(S2="")&--(T2="")&--(U2="")&--(V2="")&--(W2="")&--(X2="")&--(Y2="")&--(Z2=""))))
```

.

**UPDATE**

Here is a shorter version that works the same way. No extra columns required:

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET(B2,,,,-1+FIND("000",
 RIGHT(DEC2BIN(SUM(256,(LEN(B2:I2)>0)*2^{7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0})),8)&
 RIGHT(DEC2BIN(SUM(256,(LEN(J2:Q2)>0)*2^{7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0})),8)&
 RIGHT(DEC2BIN(SUM(256,(LEN(R2:Y2)>0)*2^{7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0})),8)&--(Z2<>"")
 )))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: kudos just for typing all that out!

Answer (score 2):

I think most worksheet functions are going to get pretty messy for this type of task, however, one way you could go about it is something like this...

`=COUNT(INDIRECT("R[0]C[1]:R[0]C[" & FIND("0",CONCATENATE(SUM(B1:D1),SUM(C1:E1), SUM(D1:F1), SUM(E1:G1), SUM(F1:H1), SUM(G1:I1), SUM(H1:J1), SUM(I1:K1), SUM(J1:L1), SUM(K1:M1), SUM(L1:N1), SUM(M1:O1), SUM(N1:P1), SUM(O1:Q1), SUM(P1:R1), SUM(Q1:S1), SUM(R1:T1), SUM(S1:U1), SUM(T1:V1), SUM(U1:W1), SUM(V1:X1), SUM(W1:Y1), SUM(X1:Z1), SUM(Y1:AA1), SUM(Z1:AB1))) & "]",FALSE))`

[image]

This works for columns A to Z, of course, it ends up being very long.  Alternatively, more options are on the table if you enable iterative calculations, then you can use something like this.

In A1: `=COUNT(INDIRECT("R[0]C[3]:R[0]C[" & B1 & "]", FALSE))`
In B1: `IF(C1 > 0,B1+ 1,B1)`
In C1: `=COUNT(INDIRECT("R[0]C[" & B1 - 2 & "]:R[0]C[" & B1  & "]",FALSE))`

[image]

The problem with this is it requires iterative calculations and is only valid if it begins its iteration with range B1 having a starting value of 0.  One way you could streamline an iteration reset would be with a switch like this...

In B1: `=IF(B2="",IF(C1 > 0,B1+ 1,B1),0)`

A VBA function is likely your best bet if you can pull it off. You could build something like this...

```
Function CountBeforeBlanks(R As Range)
    For i = 1 To R.Count
        CountBeforeBlanks = CountBeforeBlanks + R(i)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(R(i), R(i + 1), R(i + 2)) = 0 Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```